# How to get rid of a weird form border on focus

Tags: html, css, border, onfocus

Ayo,

I have built a contact form and every time I click on a specific input field to fill it out, it imitates a weird blue border around the input field.

I think the best way to present you the problem with code is if you visit my website - I don't know which of my 1k line in css triggers that so please take a look to the very bottom of the website [https://www.adamsochorec.com/about/[](https://www.adamsochorec.com/about/%5B) ](https://www.adamsochorec.com/about/)

I've tried to remove it by setting *border:* to *none*  on *:focus* but that did not work and the effect isn't generally visible while I inspect the page. So I was wondering if it might be some browser preset or something? It is both on Brave and Safari browsers.
[no outline before clicking in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkFjL.png),
[image]
[outline after clicking in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUXeN.png)
[image]

EDIT: *Outline: none* worked!

Comment: it is for accessibility reasons. you can ignore it using `button:focus { outline: none; }`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an input, you can use:

```
input:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

You can replace `input` with `textarea` or anything else in your case.